# Select file/directory path using QFileDialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I want to show a dialog to user to select a file/directory in qt. 
I tried using QFileDialog methods to get it, but either i can set file mode or directory mode, could not able to set both. if I set QFileDialog::Directory as file mode it shows directories as well as files, but could not able to select any file.

Here is the example code I tried...

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog,true);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
dialog.setNameFilterDetailsVisible(true);
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
QStringList filters;
filters <<"Any files (*)"
        <<"Text files (*.txt)"
        <<"Image files (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)";
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::HideNameFilterDetails,false);
dialog.setNameFilters(filters);
int res = dialog.exec();    
QDir directory;
QString file =  directory.currentPath();

if (res)
{
    directory = dialog.selectedFiles()[0];
    QStringList filesList = directory.entryList(QDir::Files);
    QString fileName;

    foreach(fileName, filesList)
    {
        qDebug() << "FileName " << fileName;
    }
}
```

Is there is any way get the path of selected file or directory ?

Comment: If you set FileMode to ``QFileDialog::Directory`` a valid selection can only be a directory (while all files are shown). See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum